# How to delete a file in dl.free.fr?

Tags: file-sharing

By accident, I have uploaded a file on the public file sharing service dl.free.fr through Cairo-Dock's DND2Share applet (drag and drop to share) and I would like to remove it.

It seems dl.free.fr's web and FTP interfaces would normally provide a link to delete the file, but DND2Share only gives me the link for downloading it. I have only found this looking for some kind of log on my computer (GNU/Linux):

```
[user@host ~]$ cat ~/.config/cairo-dock/dnd2share/history.conf 
[item_1397172636]
site=1
date=1397172636
type=4
url0=http://dl.free.fr/*********
url1=http://tinyurl.com/*******
local path=/home/user/Documents/myFile.zip
```

The service should automatically delete the file after 30 days without downloads, but I'd prefer it to be sooner. How can I find the link to delete the file and/or delete it directly?

Comment: Were you able to remove the file? I made the same mistake as well with confidential information.